# Supabase: How to build a content admin page that returns multiple tables with sorting and earching?

Tags: supabase

I have a supabase database with various tables like `article`, `discussions`, and `product`.

I'm using javascript and their javascript client to access the database, and it's all working fine.

However I need to code an admin page that displays all the content from these three tables, with the ability to sort by date (all tables have a `date` column), to search by title (all tables also have a `title` column), and with a pagination.

I will also need this capability for other things like displaying a feed that displays content from multiple tables, ordered by a common column (most likely `date`)

Obviously I'm now running into the issue that the Supabase javascript client cannot return content from multiple tables.

I can write a custom SQL query and save it as a view:

```
WITH combined_content AS (
  SELECT 'post' AS type, id, title, created
  FROM article
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'article' AS type, id, title, created
  FROM article
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'product' AS type, id, title, created
  FROM product
)
SELECT *
FROM combined_content
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But views don't accept arguments, so I can't build a pagination, sorting, or searching capability.

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: _"javascript client to access the database"_ - how are you keeping your access-keys secure?

Comment: _"Obviously I'm now running into the issue that the Supabase javascript client cannot return content from multiple tables."_ - so make 3 separate requests

Comment: I won't be able to build a proper pagination or sorting system with 3 separate requests

Comment: ...and why is that?

Comment: Let's say I want to display the 30 items across all 3 tables, ordered by date. With 3 separate requests, I get the most recent 10 items of each table, and then aggregate them. This is different from getting the 30 most recent across all 3 tables.

Comment: Create a `VIEW` that performs a `UNION` of all items from all desired tables, selecting a constant string as a table/entity identifier, the date/time value, and the PK, then perform your search over that `VIEW` with pagination performed afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That's what I initially thought, but views don't accept arguments so I can't dynamically change the limit or the "order by".

Comment: You don't need to - you put that part in the outer script which invokes the view.

Comment: Do you mean the javascript that calls the view? I've called the view "all_content", and I'm calling it with `supabase.from("all_content").select()`; But I'm not aware of anything we can pass to the view. Or do you mean using a database function to call the view?

Comment: Ah, right - I just figured out we can use the javascript wrapper to query views. So it's possible to do something like supabase.from("all_content").select().order('created'). That solves my issue.